# Корректный парсер дат

Tags: php, дата, время

Скрипт получает из разных источников строку которая содержит время и(или) дату в разных форматах, возможно есть универсальный способ без каких либо велосипедов корректно распарсить эти данные, для дальнейшего сохранения в базу в едином формате? Как вы решаете данную проблему?

вот несколько примеров:

```
13.08.16 07:35
01:20 (если не указана дата то указываем текущую)
3/09/2016 07:35
3.9.16 7:01
```

и т.д

Comment: Пишите велосипед. В PHP за несколько лет появилось уйма функций для работы с датами и почти все функции парсинга не учитывают особенностей неанглийской нотации. Собственно их из-за того и появилось много, поскольку все они неудачные

Comment: попробуйте "корректно распарсить": `03/09/2016` и `09/03/2016`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в php есть встроенный класс DateTime для работы с датами/периодами дат и прочим.
который позволяет использовать даже вот такой синтаксис

`$firstDayOfPastMonth->modify("0:00:00 first day of previous month");`

для парсинга дат, конечно существует [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

пример оттуда же:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

всяческие обвязки на его основе вы можете использовать по своему желанию и усмотрению, а изобретать велосипеды на strtotime следует только когда вам нужно распарсить что-то в UNIX timestamp, он только для этого создан.

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, его и решил использовать, единственное что усложняет работу так это то что нужно прописывать четкий шаблон даты, вместо этого хотелось бы указывать только порядок расположения день/месяц/год/час/минута после этого класс бы распознавал в каких фортах они записаны

Comment: (перечитал коммент)  для этого можно дописать обвязку, возможно даже не очень сложную. по сути дела массив форматов->указатели на обработчики, или набор кейсов. можно абстрагироваться еще выше на уровень декларативных правил

Comment: Что такое декларативные правила? можно пример

Comment: ну ты пишешь yaml/json/ можно и файл с php-настройками, в них указываешь только порядок расположения дат и всякие дополнительные настройки, если тебе нужно, парсишь их, а потом используешь их в той же обвязке из массивов функций/кейсов. Но это уже очень зависит от задачи, если у тебя проект, который будет использоваться многими людьми, и т.д. Если не мегапроект, то не гонись за мегагибкостью

Comment: Ну - как пример: я однажды построил чисто декларативную систему построения интерфейсов к mysql-запросам на json. Ты пишешь простой json-файл, получаешь новый инструмент репортов в админке, со всеми инпутами, выборами дат и т.д. Это было оправдано, поскольку он уже пять лет используется для больших и не очень денег и им пользуются программисты, менеджеры и топ-менеджеры

Answer (score 1):

В PHP есть функция [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) Все остальное - от лукавого :)

Comment: Сомнительная функция "...параметром функции должна быть строка с датой на английском языке...". А если надо распарсить "1 января 2016 г." или "01.01.2016 г."?

Comment: `$str1 = '13.08.16 07:35';
$str2 = '13/08/2016 07:35';
$str3 = '13.8.16 7:35';


echo strtotime($str1).'<br/>';
echo strtotime($str2).'<br/>';
echo strtotime($str3).'<br/>';
`  не дает результатов... белая пелена перед глазами и всё

Comment: не парсит данная функция не одну из предложенных дат

Answer (score 1):

Вот неплохая заготовка: [wapmorgan/TimeParser](https://github.com/wapmorgan/TimeParser). Осталось только добавить необходимые вам правила.

Comment: Осталось только понять, споок правил по определению конечен, а набор вариантов написания дат - бесконечен. То есть, на запрос автора "хочу чтобы за меня и пальцы загибали", увы, ответа не даёт.