# Добавление +1 к microtime date PHP

Tags: php, строки, дата, время

Есть скрипт который считает microtime

```
$date = date_create_from_format('U.u', microtime(true));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

Долго искал в мануале и вот что нашел.

при желании можно добавить к месяцу/дню/году и тд +1

```
    $nextyear  = mktime(date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
    echo date('m d y', $nextyear);            //приводим время в читаемую форму
```

Нужно подобное реализовать с микросекундами
Пробовал уже

```
 $nextyear  = mktime(date_format($date , "u")+1);
 echo date('u', $nextyear);                        //безуспешно



$nextyear  = mktime(date_format($date , "u")+1);
 echo date_format($date, 'u', $nextyear);         //тоже безуспешно
```

Пока все попытки безуспешны , может кто сталкивался и решал подобное уже?

Comment: вам сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554550/208216 (не надо велосипеды костылить, если все уже есть), и да, вы совсем не понимаете, как работает PHP.

Comment: Без комментариев.

Comment: ты не можешь просто ходить и добавлять +1  к любым данным, прости, ну т.е это просто не работает так. PHP  не может понять, что ты хочешь +1 добавить к чему? к какому вызову функции, +1 - секунда? час? миллион?

Comment: я в курсе что такое int что такое float и что такое string , да и для справки , где - то в мануале php написано что теоретически можно добавить +1 к любому значению , хоть буквенному количеству символов.
Правда это не практично и никому не нужно .

Comment: @strangeqargo Пока что DateTime не умеет производить операции с точностью микросекунд. Минимальная единица времени - секунда.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй использовать плюсики... Если я правильно тебя понял, то вот примеры:

```
$i = 5; // 5

$i++; // 6

$k = 3; // 3

$k = $k+1; // 4

echo $i; // вывод 6

echo $k; // вывод 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно оперировать как числом, брать вторую часть от microtime, добавлять к ней что нужно и вновь возращаться к формату microtime.

```
function mk_add( $add ) {
    $mk = explode(" ",microtime());
    $mk[1] = $mk[1] + $add;
    return implode(" ",$mk);
}
```

Comment: да , это я сразу понял , но дело в том что мне нужно прибавлять + 1 мс к числу вида 2016 10 30 03 10 20 999 . и как мы все знаем если у пользователя при генерации получатся последние 5 чисел как 59 999 то при прибавлении +1 мс это будет 60 000 , а 60 секунды в минуте как мы знаем не бывает)

Answer (score 0):

Можно отформатировать дату обратно в "U.u" и добавить микросекунду. 
Пока время умещается в double должно быть нормально.

```
function add_1ms( $date ){
    return date_create_from_format( 'U.u', date_format( $date, "U.u" ) + 0.0001 );
}

$date = date_create_from_format( 'U.u', microtime( true ) );
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
echo date_format( $date, $format ) . "\n";
echo date_format( add_1ms( $date ), $format ) . "\n";
```